# Firebase firestore,auth,storage Version error

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I am using using firestore,auth and storage. I know all the versions of them should be same.
before:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

this works fine

but now I have to use

```
documentReference2.update("test", FieldValue.arrayUnion(documentReference));
```

So I need to use the newer version of firestore. I tried changing it to 19.0.0,18.0.0,16 etc for all of them. I tried every possible way. But always gives the

> error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0
>   base:firebase-storage:16.0.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure
>   dialog

I'm unable to find a solution

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: yes works fine.ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the following:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

into this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
```

Check the latest versions here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions